How to encode data for use in charm-crypto's attribute based encryption?
I'm using Charm Crypto from Github. I'd like to use the attribute based encryption algorithms. The test code works fine, however, it uses a random message generated from PairingGroup. How do I use my own data for encryption?
group = PairingGroup('SS512', secparam=512)
msg = group.random(GT)
// do something
ct = maabe.encrypt(msg, ...)

I want to try this with "Hello world!" with this schemes https://jhuisi.github.io/charm/charm/schemes/abenc/abenc_dacmacs_yj14.html
encode data for use in charm-crypto's attribute based encryption
